# The usage of Past Perfect tense

Tags: word-usage, tenses, past-perfect

Good time of the day! I just wanted to clarify something with your help. Is it pertinent to use past perfect in this case, assuming that I am talking fully in the context of the past:

> I wasn't able to watch the full report because it had been abruptly discontinued.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - perfectly correct.

"Abruptly discontinued" was a past status, when the time marker of "I wasn't able to watch" occurred.

It is the classic use of the "past perfect" - or "pluperfect" as it would be called in Latin.

Comment: Thank you, good sir!